# Procedure for doing sex without committing a sin

Tags: nikah, sex

Peace be upon everyone!

I am nervous as I am not used to share my concerns regarding this matter online but I believe that we as muslims are always supporting to each other.

I have been scattering websites on the web to learn about the correct procedure to have the sex with my husband but I fear committing a wrong doing that I would regret and force myself not to have a physical touch with my husband anymore.

Sometimes during sex we start making noises and have a conversation while playing the Quran al kareem on TV but I am not sure if this is a sunnah thing to do as I feel that this would be an insult to the holy book and would be something satan would be pleased to have.

Moreover, my husband orders me to wear the hijab while remaining naked from top to bottom during the sex and I also feel not comfortable about this but I have to abide by my husband.

Therefore, my question is how do we practice sex carefully and correctly and how should the surrounding environment be to avoid any noises or sounds that might come from us (should we play the Quran on TV?)?

I fear browsing other western websites that might contain information and graphic images that are haram.

Comment: Without a doubt playing or being able to hear Quran in the background is not the best thing to do in such an intimate moment. It's disrespectful, as we are commanded to listen to it when we hear it. So stop doing that. About that wearing hijab, it sounds like a personal fetish. Talk about it to your husband and come to an understanding. Plus, there are various good books and articles written about how we should and should not be intimate with spouse, try reading. There cannot be one definite answer. Just avoid the Haram, that's the least you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alykom wa rahmut allah wa barakatoh (peace be upon muslims).

Dear sister, I understand your frustration and concerns but I must warn you that playing the Quran al kareem (the book that descended from the seventh sky, the book that many muslims lost life defending it) while performing sex is an insult to those who died to raise the word of allah. Therefore, please avoid that.

Moreover, you must abide by your husband's commands especially when it comes to performing the acts in order to satisfy his urges and your urges. Therefore, always please your husband and fulfil his pleasure and may Allah save us from the great fire ameen.